How to connect a file from a folder in a different branch?
So im trying to link the css from my home folder, and my favicon to one of my pages in a different branch/folder, but it isnt working.
my code
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TheAlphaLeopard</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../home/imgs/favicon.ico"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../home/styles.css" />
</head>


I tried using the ../ before my code, but it isnt linking the files corectly.

Should be ../../. The home folder doesn't look like its under apps .

It isnt, I was wondering if I could link files from home onto my chess folder. I thought if you used multiple ..s then you could keep going up folders. I have just found out that isnt true.

You need to move up two levels, since your html file path is
THEALPHA.../app/chess/index.html and your css file is in th folder
THEAPHA.../home/styles.css
<link rel="stylehseet" type="text/css" href="../../home/styles.css">

Try to figure out, in which index.html file you are really working before you start.
proTip: Don't mix up branch and folder in IT.

Thanks a lot! Would this be connsidered branch or folder?.. Sorry iḿ new to this...

Folder. The term branch is used in the context of versioning: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell
